# How can I integrate MoEngage SDK for push notifications in both frontend and backend?

Tags: android, push-notification

I'm unsure about integrating it into my backend. I lack knowledge on integrating SDKs into backend systems. Could someone provide guidance on integrating MoEngage SDK into my backend system? What specific APIs do I need to use to send push notifications to users?

I'm looking for examples/documentation on using MoEngage APIs for push notifications. What parameters/headers are necessary for hitting MoEngage APIs? Do I use a MoEngage-provided SDK for backend integration or directly use RESTful APIs? What are the integration steps? How does the app id and firebse cloud messaging authentication gets used?

I have looked into the documentation. Any insights, code examples, or references would be appreciated.